# Can a time-based workflow trigger every time a record is created or edited?

Tags: workflow, administration

Sorry this isn't a programming question, but I trust folks on this site moreso than elsewhere.

I'm signed up to take the ADM201 test and am reviewing questions people have posted on the Internet.  One question that popped [here (14th one down)](http://quizlet.com/12816179/sfdc-adm-201-practice-exam-1-flash-cards/) and [here (#203)](http://salesforceadm201.blogspot.com/p/page-3.html) asks: Time based workflow can be triggered every time a record is created or edited.    The answer given is True.

To me, this isn't right.  [From the help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_settings.htm&siteLang=en_US): Time dependent workflow actions cannot be used when a record is "created, and every time it's edited".  They can be used, however, when "created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria".

Now, I don't believe everything I read on the Internet but I've seen this same exact question in a number of different places answered true so it's got me doubting myself.  Opinions/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you look at it.

Since the wording says "Triggered" the answer would be yes as if it is edited to meet the criteria it is triggered and if you insert it can be triggered if it meets the criteria. In addition, it says a "Time Based Workflow" which implies the workflow meets the criteria to be using a time based action.

Since it is not talking about when you can add a time based action to a workflow (the answer would then be false).

So if you take the question at face value and only according to the wording in the question without reading anything into it then TRUE would be the answer

Comment: Yeah it would be better to say it is reevaluated each time the record is edited

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  Problem is tests want the 'best' answer which I feel means a strict interpretation of the question.  IMO "Time-based workflow"  must be a Time Dependent Action (because Immediate Workflow Actions don't have a time element in them).  Since 'Created, and every time its edited' is specifically disallowed in SF I'd marked the answer as false.    In any case, I now realize both links have the exact same questions and ultimately lead you to a website selling practice certification questions.   Upon that realization my opinion of these questions just plummeted...

Comment: @Scott - A time based workflow is one that ALREADY has a Time Dependent Action - Hence why TRUE is the best answer. The limit you describe is related to adding a time dependent action to a workflow.

Comment: I see your point, @Eric.  The other place strict interpretation applies is with "can be" - not that it is but rather that it might trigger.  So, I change my mind and agree that TRUE is the best answer.  Tricky wording...